# Разница между "где" и "в которой"

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли не различать "гимназия, где она преподавала в 2001 году" и "гимназия, в которой она преподавала в 2001 году", или есть какие-то нюансы?

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, можно не различать. Значение уж точно одно и то же. Стилистические нюансы? Кто любит, может высасывать из пальца.

Comment: Чем объяснить причину ошибок? Нужный палец забинтован...

Comment: В каких источниках Вы нашли утверждение, что варианты однозначны?  А то Ваш ответ похож на ответ оракула (жуете листья  лавра, пьете воду из священного ручья - и отвечаете).

Comment: Это из той же серии, почему в "мама мыла раму" запятой не требуется. Или: докажи, что ты не верблюд. Или дважды два четыре... Примеры можно умножать. Не кажется ли вам, что бремя доказывания в подобных случаях ложится но того, кто утверждает наличие? А не отсутствие.

Comment: Мне так не кажется. Вы утверждаете полное тождество  двух разных союзных слов, так хотя бы  ссылку  из какого-никакого учебника приведите. Я считаю, что это не ответ, а ничем не обоснованное суждение, которому мы почему-то должны доверять.

Comment: Я не утверждаю "полного тождества союзных слов". Я утверждаю практически полное равенство фраз, приведенных в вопросе. И уж мой ответ, смею думать, гораздо лучше того, что идёт следом за вашим. "Зависит от того, какая часть известна собеседнику" и тому подобные  умствования. И почему _этим_ суждениям мы должны доверять?

Answer (score 1):

Местоимение "который" характерно для книжной речи, в нейтральном стиле его по возможности заменяют местоименными наречиями (где, куда, откуда и др.), однако такая замена **должна соответствовать структуре предложения, например:**

(1) Её новый знакомый оказался директором  (какой?) гимназии, **в которой** она преподавала в 2001 году.  (2) Документы находились  (где?) в гимназии, где она преподавала в 2001 году.

Оба придаточных являются определительными, но во втором предложении это обстоятельственное определение и **замена желательна, чтобы избежать повтора предлога В.**  В первом предложении местоимение "в которой" в большей степени соответствует определительному значению придаточного.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта приводят одну и ту же информацию о даме (указание на место её преподавательской деятельности в 2001 году). Нюансы донесения этой инфомации (выбор того или иного варианта) зависят от того, какая часть её известна собеседнику - по мнению говорящего (он может знать это напр. по им же *ранее сказанному*). Если собеседнику или адресату известно только то, что она была преподавателем, то вариант с "**где**" (= а преподавала она **в гимназии**, и было это в 2001 году - единственный эпизод в её работе) косвенно это учитывает. Если же адресату известно, что дама - исключительно гимназическая учительница, то это учитывается вариантом с "**в которой**" (= вы уже знаете, что преподавала она **в разных гимназиях**, речь сейчас о **той из них**, в которой она работала в 2001 году). Разумется, далеко не все разборчивы в таких нюансах: кто-то в любой ситуации употребляет исключительно один из таких вариантов, кто-то - первый попавшийся, а какой-нибудь литератор (с участием редактора) делает сознательный выбор.

Comment: Не совсем точно. Слова "в которой" могут выделять данную гимназию не только из гимназий, в которых она преподавала, но и, например, из всех гимназий этого города. Сравните: "Дом, в котором мы живем" (в городе много домов, а это - тот, в котором мы живем)

Comment: Ну вот, я ж говорил... Любители высасывать из пальца быстро нашлись. ) В городе много домов, а это – тот, где мы живём. Или в котором? Или где? "Вы офицер или где?" – вот тут уж точно не заменишь.